# Regex for DLP NAtional ID

Tags: regex

I am working on regex for national ID, ID number is content with 11 digits and always starts with 3 or 2.

I have developed following regex, but this is detecting within other set of numbers as well.

We want to detect only if this started with 2 only. Any suggestions ?

```
(^\s([2-3])|[2-3])\d{11}
```

Comment: Why not just `2\d{10}`? What’s the purpose of `\s` in your attempt?

Comment: “*but this is detecting within other set of numbers as well*” What other set of numbers are you talking about? Can you edit your question to clarify exactly why this existing pattern doesn’t meet your requirements? Can you provide sample inputs and whether you’d expect each to match or not?

Comment: 2\d{10} isn't working at all. Refer my answers inline.

Comment: Try `\b[23]\d{10}\b` https://regex101.com/r/YTFNsC/1 for a total of 11 digits, or `\b[23]\d{11}\b` for a total of 12 digits